# Как получить текст сообщения бота в aiogram?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, sendmessage

Как получить текст сообщения бота в aiogram?
Получить текст сообщения пользователя это message.text
А вот как поймать тот текст, который отправил бот?

Comment: а зачем вам «ловить» то, что вы сами и отправили?

Comment: Тут в двух словах и не объяснишь), пользователь нажимает кнопку с номером вопроса и бот присылает сам вопрос, а после этого пользователь отвечает на вопрос видеосообщением, которое сохраняется в БД.Так вот, нужно к каждому видео прикрепить на какой же вопрос отвечал пользователь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так можно

```py
prev_msg = await message.anwer("text")
```